# Where do I apply for Schengen Visa?

Tags: visas, schengen

I'll be travelling to Europe from 30th May to 13th June. I plan on reaching Vienna on the morning of 30th and leaving for Prague on 2nd July. From there, I'll travel to Krakow on 5th July. From there on 8th July, I'll leave for Bratislava. And from Bratislava to Budapest on 10th July. I'll leave Budapest on 13th July.

Since my time of staying in each country is almost the same, should I apply at the Austrian Embassy since they'll be my point of entry? 
Also, I haven't purchased tickets for flights yet. Is it necessary or just giving the itinerary of flights I plan to use work? I came across websites offering flight reservations for a nominal fee. Should I use that?

Comment: Not exactly. That guy's asking where he should enter from if he already has a visa. I don't have a visa yet, I'm asking where should I apply.

Answer (score 4):

Your itinerary:

> AT: 30 May to 2 June, 4 days
> CZ: 2 June to 5 June, 4 days
> PL: 5 June to 8 June, 4 days
> SK: 8 June to 10 June, 3 days
> HU: 10 June to 13 June, 4 days

You must apply to the consulate of the country that is your main destination.  This is specified in the [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412), Article 5(1)(b):

> Article 5
>
> Member State competent for examining and deciding on an application
>
> 1. The Member State competent for examining and deciding on an application for a uniform visa shall be:
>
> (a) [not applicable]
>
> (b) if the visit includes more than one destination, the Member State whose territory constitutes the main destination of the visit(s) in terms of the length or purpose of stay; or

Thus, the main destination may be determined either in terms of the length of your stay or its purpose.  Since you include no information about the purpose of your visit, we can assume for the sake of argument that you are touring, and have no special plan (for example a meeting or a conference) in any one country.

By the length of your stay, you cannot distinguish a main destination.  Therefore, you should look at 5(1)(c):

> (c) if no main destination can be determined, the Member State whose external border the applicant intends to cross in order to enter the territory of the Member States.

You should therefore apply to Austria unless you will be flying to Vienna through another Schengen country, in which case you should apply to that country.

Comment: Great. Thanks! Could you also help me regarding my doubt about the flight reservation?

Comment: @user3193439 I'm not sure, but you can ask that as a separate question.